# sql GROUP BY takes too long

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, aggregate-functions

The following query seems not to end, because of the GROUP BY.

Without the GROUP BY, it returns records without waiting

Could you give some ideas to try ?

Thanks in advance

```
   SELECT 
         MPHIST_LF.ID_MEASURING_POINT AS MP_LF,
         MPHIST_LF.FROM_DATE AS FROM_LF,
         MPHIST_LF.TO_DATE AS TO_LF, 
         RM.ID_FARE AS FARE_LF,
         COUNT(*)
   FROM RE_MPOINT_HIST MPHIST_LF
        INNER JOIN ME_MEA_CTYPE_HIST CTHIST_LF ON CTHIST_LF.ID_MEASURER = MPHIST_LF.ID_MEASURER
        INNER JOIN ME_MEASURER ME ON ME.ID_MEASURER = MPHIST_LF.ID_MEASURER
        INNER JOIN ME_COMBINATION_USAGE_TYPE CUT ON ME.ID_COMBINATION_USAGE_TYPE = CUT.ID_COMBINATION_USAGE_TYPE
        INNER JOIN ME_RATE_METER RM ON RM.ID_RATE_METER = CUT.ID_RATE_METER
   WHERE CTHIST_LF.COD_USAGE_TYPE = 'AE0' 
        AND CUT.COD_DH = 'CODDH00001'
        AND (RM.ID_FARE  = 1000072 OR RM.ID_FARE = 1002253)
        AND (RM.COD_GESTION IS NULL OR RM.COD_GESTION =  'TYPCLI0003')
   GROUP BY MPHIST_LF.ID_MEASURING_POINT,MPHIST_LF.FROM_DATE,MPHIST_LF.TO_DATE, RM.ID_FARE 
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2


GCGT_ME_MEASURER:  
  IDX_GCGTMEMEASURER_01 >> ID_MEASURER, RELEVANT_EQUIP   
  PK_GCGT_ME_MEASURER >> ID_MEASURER 
  IDX_GCGT_ME_MEASURER_99 >> ID_DEVICE   

GCGT_ME_COMBINATION_USAGE_TYPE:  
  IDX_FK_ME_COM_US_TY_DEV_TY_01 >> COD_DEVICE_TYPE 
  PK_GCGT_ME_COMB_USAGE_TYPE >> ID_COMBINATION_USAGE_TYPE    

GCGT_ME_MEA_CTYPE_HIST:  
  IDX_MEA_CTYPE_HIST_01 >> ID_MEASURER 
  IDX_MEA_CTYPE_HIST >> ID_MEA_CTYPE_HIST 

GCGT_ME_RATE_METER:  
  IDX_FK_ME_RATE_TY_RE_SPEC_01 >> COD_SPECIALIZATION 
  PK_GCGT_ME_RATE_METER >> ID_RATE_METER         

GCGT_RE_MPOINT_HIST:  
  IDX_GCGT_RE_MPOINHHIST_03 >> ID_MEASURING_POINT, ID_MEASURER, ID_MP_NATURE, ID_COMBINATION_USAGE_TYPE, ID_RATE_METER 
  IDX_GCGT_RE_MPOINHHIST_01 >> ID_MEASURING_POINT 
  IDX_GCGT_RE_MPOINHHIST_02 >> ID_MEASURER 
  GCGT_RE_MP_HIST_NAT_01 >> ID_MP_NATURE 
  IDX_MPOINT_HIST >> ID_MPOINT_HIST  

Record count: 8064087, without the aggregate.    

Statistcs up to date with, for instance: ::::: 
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('user', 'RE_MPOINT_HIST');
```

Without the aggregate function, the results are shown in seconds. Could be that not all the results are shown. The count(*) without the aggregate lasts about 20 or 25 minutes.

All indexes were REBUILDED.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| Id  | Operation                          | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                                |  3970 |   302K|  4622   (1)| 00:00:56 |  
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                     |                                |  3970 |   302K|  4622   (1)| 00:00:56 |  
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                     |                                |       |       |         |     |  
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                    |                                |  3970 |   302K|  4621   (1)| 00:00:56 |  
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                   |                                |  4371 |   290K|  1997   (1)| 00:00:24 |  
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                  |                                |  2551 |   107K|   466   (0)| 00:00:06 |  
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                 |                                |     1 |    33 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|   7 |        INLIST ITERATOR             |                                |       |       |            |          |
|*  8 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| GCGT_ME_RATE_METER             |     1 |    21 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|*  9 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FK_GCGT_ME_RATE_GCCOM_FARE_01  |     4 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|* 10 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | GCGT_ME_COMBINATION_USAGE_TYPE |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|* 11 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN           | FK_ME_COM_US_TY_RATE_METER_01  |     6 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|  12 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | GCGT_ME_MEASURER               |  8574 | 85740 |   464   (0)| 00:00:06 |  
|* 13 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN            | FK_ME_MEASURER_ME_COMB_US_01   | 17368 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|  14 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | GCGT_RE_MPOINT_HIST            |     2 |    50 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|* 15 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IDX_GCGT_RE_MPOINHHIST_02      |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|* 16 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN               | IDX_MEA_CTYPE_HIST_01          |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
|* 17 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | GCGT_ME_MEA_CTYPE_HIST         |     1 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Looks pretty clean. How many results without the aggregate?

Comment: How many records does it return without the group by? Are you sure it returns *all of them* immediately or just the first view? Because a "GROUP BY" will force some materialization whereas without it the DB can stream the results and provide the first ones much earlier.

Comment: are the indexes and statistics current/fresh? have you looked at an explain plan?

Comment: Could you please show us the explain plan of the query? But do not forget to gather the statistics at first.

Comment: Which columns in the various tables have indexes?

Comment: @IGNACIOCEMELI Please edit your answer instead of putting that in comments.

Comment: @IGNACIOCEMELI Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24935114/edit) link on your question to post these extra details. It is far too difficult to extract this from the comments.

Comment: The best way to tune these long-running queries is with SQL Monitoring.  Run the query, and right after it finishes run `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '[enter sql_id here]', type => 'text') from dual;`  Post the *whole* results here we'll have plenty of information to look at.  My initial guess is that the optimizer is under-estimating cardinality, and it would be better to convert some nested loop joins to hash joins.

Comment: How to change from nested loop join to hash join ?

Comment: The quickest way is with a hint like `SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(MPHIST_LF ME_MEA_CTYPE_HIST) */`.  But hints are tricky, it will take some experimenting to get it right.

Comment: Tested hint use_hash and the result was much better. I would like to get those HASH JOIN without hints. Statistics, PGA memory, but I do not succeded. Any help ?

Comment: This is where things get tricky.  Most likely one of your columns has skewed data.  For example, `COD_USAGE_TYPE` may have 100 values but `AE0` has 99% of the data.  Then the optimizer would estimate it only returns 1% of the data instead of 99%.  If that's the case, look into adding histograms - they may help the optimizer understand which column values are popular, leading to improved cardinality estimates, leading to improved access methods and join orders.  Normally the histograms are created automatically, you may want to look into your statistics gathering methods and preferences.

Comment: How to know which columns have Skewed data ? May I use  method_opt=>'for all indexed columns size skewonly' for the optimizer to guess himself ?

Comment: I was hoping that you'd know which column was skewed just based on the data.  The default statistics gathering method might be good enough, but be sure to run it *after* you've ran the query so Oracle knows which columns are used.  The explain plan helps, but explain plans are only *estimates*.  If you look at the SQL Monitoring reports it will tell you the estimates and the *actual values*.  That will tell us exactly which operation is taking the most time, and which estimates are the most wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. create one temp table to stores the count and ID information.
2. Left join this count temp table.
3. Filter what count data are you need.

Comment: But then the saved time goes to the temporary table creation ? or do you mean within the query ? Thanks